# Python Threading: Continuing a thread until other thread ends

Tags: python, multithreading

Here's my code:

```
import threading
import time


class Threadd(threading.Thread):
    def main(self):

        time.sleep(4)
        print("One")
        self.var = True
        return self.var

def threadmain():
    print("Foo")
    threadobj = Threadd()
    threadd = threading.Thread(target=threadobj.main)
    threadd.start()

    time.sleep(5)
    print("Done")

    mainthread = threading.Thread(target=threadmain)
    mainthread.start()
```

I need "mainthread" to keep running until 'threadd' is finished, how can I do this?

Comment: Read: https://kite.com/python/examples/454/threading-wait-for-a-thread-to-finish

Comment: What does "keep running" mean? Do you mean you need it to continue _doing_ something? or do you merely mean you need it to not exit? If you merely need it to wait (i.e., not exit), then @jeremyfriesner's answer is the ticket: use `join()`. If you need it to keep doing something, then that probably means it will have a _loop_, and somewhere in the loop, you'll want it to check to see whether the other thread has finished or not. I would have it check by looking at some variable that the other thread sets when the other thread is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to wait until a child thread has exited is have the main/parent thread call `join()` on the child thread.  `join()` will block until the child thread has exited, so after `join()` returns you know the child thread has gone away and it is safe to continue.  Here's an example usage:

```
import threading
import time

class Threadd(threading.Thread):
    def main(self):
        print("Child thread starts running")
        time.sleep(4)
        self.var = True
        print("Child thread is done running")
        return self.var

print("Main thread launching child thread")
threadobj = Threadd()
threadd = threading.Thread(target=threadobj.main)
threadd.start()

print("Main thread waiting for child thread to exit...")
threadd.join()
print("Child thread exited, so we can exit too -- bye!")
```